# Removing eventhandlers not working: "this" context lost in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

I have a problem with removing the eventhandlers for a slider element

If I don't use proxy for the handler, the "this" will point to the dom element

How do I remove the handler?

**Relevant code:**

```
var slider = (function (slider) {
    
    
var Sliderhandle = function(handle){
    EvtTarget.call(this);
    
    this.events = { 
        start: ['touchstart', 'mousedown'],
        move: ['touchmove', 'mousemove'],
        end: ['touchend', 'touchcancel', 'mouseup']
    };
    
    this.options = {};
    this.element = $$('div.ui-slider');
    // set context for event handlers
    this.start = this.start.bind(this);
    this.move = this.move.bind(this);
    this.end = this.end.bind(this);
    
    this.proxy = function(func){
        var that = this;
        return(function(){
         return func.apply(that,arguments); 
        });
    }
    
    Object.defineProperty(this, "__el",{
        value:handle
    });
    
};


    Sliderhandle.prototype = Object.create(EvtTarget.prototype,{
        init : {
            value:function(config){
                
                

                this.container = $$('div.ui-slider');                                                                      
                this.track = this.container.getElementsByClassName('ui-slider-track')[0];
                
                this.value = (config && config.value) || 1;
                this.min = (config && config.min) || 1;
                this.max = (config && config.value) || 1000;
                this.change = (config && config.change) || null; // callback
                
                this.addEvents("start");
                this.setValue(this.value);
                
            },
            enumerable:true
        },
        
        addEvents : {
            value:function(name){
                var list = this.events[name], 
                    handler = this[name],
                    all;
                handler = this.proxy(handler);
                for (all in list){
                  this.container.addEventListener(list[all], handler, false);
                }       
            },
            enumerable:true
        },
        removeEvents:{
            value:function(name){
                var list = this.events[name], 
                    handler = this[name],
                    all;
                //handler = this.proxy(handler);   
                for (all in list){
                  this.container.removeEventListener(list[all], handler, false);
                }
            },
            enumerable:true
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because there's no event listener same with `handler` which passed to `removeEventListener`. `this.proxy()` generates new function for each call. It returns whole different *function object* even if you call it with same parameter, although the returned function will do semantically same job.

You should store proxy functions when add, then use that one when remove like this:

```
var Sliderhandle = function(handle){
    // ....
    this.proxyHandler = {};
}

// ....

addEvents : {
    value: function(name){
        var list = this.events[name], 
            handler = this[name],
            all;
        this.proxyHandler[name] = handler = this.proxy(handler);
        for (all in list){
            this.container.addEventListener(list[all], handler, false);
        }       
    },
    enumerable:true
},
removeEvents:{
    value:function(name){
        var list = this.events[name], 
            handler = this.proxyHandler[name],
            all;  
        for (all in list){
            this.container.removeEventListener(list[all], handler, false);
        }
        delete this.proxyHandler[name];
    },
    enumerable:true
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it. It never ocurred to me. Can you maybe also ex. lain why I can not get access to variables if I for example declare "events{..}" with var.

Comment: `var` declares local variable, so it only accessible within function. To declare field in JavaScript you must use `this`. (This is simplified explanation, not exact one. For further information please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: thank you, I could not test yet, because I could not connect, but I will mark your answer